# Converter de String para Integer no Pascal

Tags: string, pascal

Boa noite, estou com um problema em Pascal, pego uma variável em String, a variavel seria um Hexadecimal, preciso converter essa String para integer e não sei como fazer.
Obrigado

```html
program trabalho_integrador ;
  
var
 a, b, c, a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, calc2 : String;
 y : boolean;
 calc, i,z : integer;

begin
  write('Digite A: ');
  readln(a);
  write('Digite B: ');
  readln(b);
  write('Digite C: ');
  readln(c);


  a1 := copy(a,1,1);
  a2 := copy(a,2,1);
  b1 := copy(b,1,1);
  b2 := copy(b,2,1);
  c1 := copy(c,1,1);
  c2 := copy(c,2,1);

  z := StrToInt(a1);


  readln();

end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe a função 'StrToInt' no Pascal, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
var
  A : Integer;
```

begin
  try
    A := StrToInt('100 ');    // Converte a String '100' para integer 100.
  except
    on Exception : EConvertError do
      ShowMessage(Exception.Message);
  end;
end;

Comment: Como faço para importar a biblioteca dessa função?

Answer (score 0):

A biblioteca SysUtils possui o conversor como citado anteriormente, e também algo que recomendo que você verifique a necessidade de utilizar o StrToIntDef, seguindo o exemplo acima, pode ser utilizado da seguinte forma:

```
var
  A : Integer;
  B : Integer;


begin
  try
    A := StrToInt('100 ');    // Converte a String '100' para integer 100.
    B := StrToIntDef('Duzentos', 0); // Tenta converter o texto para inteiro, caso não consiga utiliza o valor passado no segundo parâmetro, que no caso é o 0.
  except
    on Exception : EConvertError do
      ShowMessage(Exception.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Vale lembrar que no primeiro caso entraria na exceção caso não conseguisse, na segunda ele converteria automaticamente sem gerar a exceção.